# npm run build hangs no matter what, cannot upgrade webpack

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, centos, centos7

I cloned a react repository and would like to run it. However, `npm run build` and `npm start` hang indefinitely.

I am trying to run the application on a CentOS 7 server which I access via ssh.

I am running:

`npm install`

and then

`npm run build` or `npm start`

Here is what I see:

```
my-project@ build /local/scratch/my-project/app
webpack --mode development --progress
```

The progress does not seem to display. 
I tried updating webpack with:

`npm install --global webpack@4.29.6`

I know that I need version 4.29.6 or higher. When I run this:

`npm webpack --version`

I still see version 3.10.10. My package.json file references version 4.29.6.

What should I try next?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: On a related note, consider installing webpack on a per-project basis, something like `npm webpack --save-dev`, and then using `npx webpack`

Comment: It's Ok if you are using your own webpack setup but I've delivered 2 production apps using create-react-app and did not feel the need to eject or write my custom webpack configurations

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes I was making above:

1) `npm webpack --version` does not show the version of webpack. Instead, it shows my version of npm.

2) I should not have installed webpack globally - this caused issues. I should have installed it locally.

The app still doesn't work...but I can build and see error messages which is a big step forward.